# How to resize a Gtk4 window?

Tags: gtk4

Here has a gtk4 window (`ApplicationWindow`) which contain a gtk `Label`. When I fill a long multi-line text in the label, the window auto become large width and height, this no problem. But I fill a short text in the label again, I want the window resize to smaller to fit the label size.
`Gtk.Widget.width_request` no effect on both label and window.

Answer (score 0):

[gtk4 Window.resizable](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/property.Window.resizable.html)

### Gtk.Window:resizable

**Type**: gboolean

**Description**

> If TRUE, users can resize the window.

**Setter method**

> `gtk_window_set_resizable`

**Getter method**

> `gtk_window_get_resizable`

Comment: I think resizable is true by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `void gtk_window_set_default_size(GtkWindow* window, int width, int height)` to set a different window height and width.